# Text in TextFormField goes to vanished

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm designing a layout in which I've a `TextFormField`. Text in `TextFormField` vanished. I want text remain on first line.

This is how it looks when I enter text

[image]

And this is how it looks when I enter more text

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 96, right: 96),
            width: 171.0,
            height: 22.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: loginPageInputDecoration(),
            ),
          ),
```

**loginPageInputDecoration**

```
 InputDecoration loginPageInputDecoration() {
  return const InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    fillColor: fTextFieldColor,
    filled: true,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase height of the Container as per your choice and the issue will be solved

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 96, right: 96),
            width: 171.0,
            height: 44.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: loginPageInputDecoration(),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I know this solution but I'm not allowed to increase the height of container.

Comment: then you can use contentPadding : EdgeInsets.zero in InputDecoration

Comment: after this text comes down.

Comment: use EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,20) but you have reduce font size